# discord.py не хочет устанавливатся после того как переустановили Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio, discord.py

```
Collecting discord.py
  Obtaining dependency information for discord.py from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/7e/5f1b24b2ced0c4b3042204f7827b57c7dcb26d368e9b0fde8cec7853cf30/discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 (from discord.py)
  Obtaining dependency information for aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/13/e929a6a50288e60ade3961b294d2f5aeb251b6579e4290a5397e484d0df9/aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Obtaining dependency information for yarl<2.0,>=1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/f4/2fdc5a11503bc61818243653d836061c9ce0370e2dd9ac5917258a007675/yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (32 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Obtaining dependency information for frozenlist>=1.1.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/dc/96647994a013bc72f3d453abab18340b7f5e222b7b7291e3697ca1fcfbd5/frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in d:\python\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (3.6)
Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (50 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running egg_info
      writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\meowhiks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8debh1kn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

C:\Users\meowhiks>python
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install multilist
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install multilist
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install multilist
```

Пытаюсь установить discord.py, ну получается пишу pip install discord.py, он пытается установится, но требуется какой-то multidict, который как мне кажется должен сам установится. В одной из строк описывается что надо скачать какой-то пакет Microsoft C++ Build Tools и ссылка туда. Ну установил какой-то установщик, оказалось обычная установка Visual Studio, ну я вот думаю, 6гб, ну как-то трафик не хочется тратить, так я хочу узнать почему раньше то устанавливался а сейчас нет. Может какая-то библиотека нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй откатить питон до 3.11 или 3.10.

На питон версии 3.12 еще не все api перешли.